# Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for each $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|U$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Useful Definition:** $f$ is *continuous* at $x_o\in X$ if for every $\epsilon >0, \exists \delta = \delta(\epsilon,x_o)<0$ such that if $x \in X$ and $\|x-x_o\|<\delta$ then $\|f(x)-f(x_o)\|<\epsilon$

$f$ is *continuous* if it is continuous for all $x\in X$.

**Useful Theorem:** $f$ is continuous (on all of $x$) $\iff$ for every open set $V$ in $R^m$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

**Exercise:** Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$.  Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for each $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|U$ is continuous.

**My attempt:**

*proof.*

($\implies$) Suppose that $f$ is continuous $\forall x\in X$.  Then there exists some open set in $V\subset Y$ such that $U \subset f^{-1}(V)$ where $f^{-1}(V)$ is open. Now since $U$ is a neighborhood it is open (I've proved that neighborhoods are open previously).  So by the Theorem above $f|U$ is continuous.

($\Longleftarrow$) Suppose that for each $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|U$ is continuous...

--
I'm not quite sure how to prove the rest of this or whether my first part of the proof was correct.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW this claim is true in topological spaces. The definition at the beginning of your post suggests that you ask here only about linear normed spaces.

Comment: Hint for $\boxed{\Leftarrow}$. If you have the neighborhoood $U\ni x_0$, you can choose $\delta_1$ such that all points fulfilling $\|x-x_0\|\le\delta_1$ are in $U$.

Comment: I want to say something along the lines of: since every $x_o$ is contained in an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x_o$  such that $f(x_o)$ is continuous we have $||x-x_o||<\delta$, and since $f(x_o)$ is continuous in each neighborhood $||f(x)-f(x_o)||<\epsilon$; and since we have this for every $x \in X$ we have shown continuity of $f$?

Comment: The "useful theorem" is usually the definition of continuity, since it holds for more general topological spaces.

Comment: What is your definition of neighbourhood? $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ iff ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this exercise is the exercise 5 in section 3 in chapter 1 on p.30 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
On p.26 in this book, there is the definition of "neighborhood":

> If $U$ is any open set containing $x_0$, we commonly refer to $U$ simply as a **neighborhood** of $x_0$.

My solution is here:

> Assume that $f$ is continuous.
> For each $x\in X$, we choose $U:=X$.
> Then, $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $f=f|U$ is continuous.

> Conversely, assume that for each $x\in X$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|U$ is continuous.
> Let $x$ be any point in $X$.
> Let $V$ be any open set in $Y$ which contains $f(x)$.
> By assumption, there is a neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $f|W$ is continuous.
> Since $(f|W)^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $W$, there is an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $(f|W)^{-1}(V)=W\cap U$.
> Since both of $W$ and $U$ are open sets in $X$, their intersection $(f|W)^{-1}(V)$ is also an open set in $X$ and $(f|W)^{-1}(V)$ contains $x$.
> Obviously, $f((f|W)^{-1}(V))\subset V$ holds.
> Therefore, $f$ is continuous.